# Does destroying scaffold in local will change/have effect in server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created controller, model and view using scaffold

```
rails generate scaffold Customer name:string
```

And then I did commit and then pushed everything in github and server. This was about a month ago. Now I need to undo the scaffold. I know I can do this by

```
rails destroy scaffold Customer
```

And this will undo the scaffold. My question is, this command `rails destroy scaffold Customer` do not generate any migration files. Then how destroying scaffold will have effect in server. How it will remove the files and models from server? Or do I have to do something else to undo the scaffold in server?

Answer (score 0):

All that `scaffold generate` does is generate files from templates, and modifies your `config/routes.rb` file. The delete option deletes the files created. You can use the `--pretend option` to see what effect the change will have without running that command. So try:

```
rails destroy scaffold Customer --pretend
```

To see what will be changed by that action. Personally as the code has already gone into production, I'd probably do `--pretend` to generate the list of files that need to be removed and then delete each one manually after a quick review to check that doing so had no adverse effect.

When you update git the removed files will be marked as such in git, and pushing the change to the server via git will remove those files.

**But, there are a couple of things to be careful of:**

Migrations: do not delete the migration after it has been pushed to production and implemented there. Instead create a new migration that will drop the customers table. That way you will not mess up the migration sequence, and you will not be left with an unused table.

Routes: Check your `config/routes.rb` afterwards as I doubt the `destroy scaffold` will correctly reconfigure that.